# Javascript identificador, contraseña

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, condiciones, contador, else

Cómo puedo modificar el siguiente programa de tal manera que...

1. Cuando el usuario o contraseña estén mal, solo indique que está mal uno de ellos, y no el: 'Error. Los datos son incorrectos' (a excepción de ambos datos mal)
2. Que el número de intentos solo se agote si hay 3 intentos fallidos (y seguidos) de usuario y contraseña a la vez.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

cont=0;
for(var i=1;i<=3;i++) {
 var identificador=prompt("Introduzca su identificador");
 var contrasena=prompt("Introduzca su contraseña");

if(identificador!='alibaba' && contrasena=='sesamo') {
  alert('usuario incorrecto');
}

if(identificador=='alibaba' && contrasena!='sesamo') {
  alert('contraseña incorrecta');
}

if(identificador=='alibaba' && contrasena=='sesamo') {
  alert('Los datos son correctos');
  break;

 }else{
  cont++;
  alert('Error. Los datos son incorrectos');
  
  if(cont==3) {
  alert('Lo siento, has agotado el número de intentos');
  } 
 }
 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

El bucle for no te va a servir para controlar lo de los 3 intentos, es mejor usar el while. Así tendras un contador por cada vez que fallas.

Por otro lado cambiando las sentencias if puedes controlar si ha introducido un dato mal o los dos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

cont=0;
while(cont < 3) {
 var identificador=prompt("Introduzca su identificador");
 var contrasena=prompt("Introduzca su contraseña");

if(identificador=='alibaba' && contrasena=='sesamo') {
  alert('Los datos son correctos');
    cont = 0;
  break;

}else{
  
    if(identificador!='alibaba' && contrasena=='sesamo') {
    alert('usuario incorrecto');
    }
    else if(identificador=='alibaba' && contrasena!='sesamo') {
      alert('contraseña incorrecta');
    }
    else{
      cont++;
    alert('Error. Los datos son incorrectos');
    }
  
  if(cont==3) {
    alert('Lo siento, has agotado el número de intentos');
  } 
 }
 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si que es mejor con while como comentas. Lo único es que esta parte: if(cont==3) {
    alert('Lo siento, has agotado el número de intentos');
  }             solo debe aparecer cuando ambos datos estan mal, habiéndose introducido las dos cosas mal las 3 veces

Comment: Entonces es cambiar en "cont++" dentro del else.